# What's the difference between NgcLoader and awesome-typescript-loader?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-cli

I'm reading this article about [@ngtools/webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/README.md) `NgcLoader` and it has the following code:

```
if (envOptions.MODE === 'prod') {
  config.module.rules.push(
    { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] }
  );
  ...
} else {
  config.module.rules.push(
    { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] }
  );
}
```

I'm wondering what's the difference between `NgcLoader` and `awesome-typescript-loader`. Why not use `NgcLoader` exclusively?